# PHP Access string inside object

Tags: php, string, object

I have an array:

```
array(2) (
  [0] => DMV\DrvrEdBundle\Entity\INSTRUCTOR object {
    id => (int) 22
    Instructor_Lic => (string) 67890
    First_Name => (string) lkioli
    Last_Name => (string) oioiodfdfd
    Email => (string) ioii@dfdd.dfd
    Status => (string) ACTIVE
    CreationDate => DateTime object {
      date => (string) 2014-05-20 09:46:03
      timezone_type => (int) 3
      timezone => (string) America/New_York
    }
    EditDate => DateTime object {
      date => (string) 2014-05-20 09:46:14
      timezone_type => (int) 3
      timezone => (string) America/New_York
    }
  }
)
```

I want to access the date string in the CreationDate Obj.  How can I access this?

Any help would be appreciated.

--- Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just:

```
$arr[0]->CreationDate->format('Y-m-d H:i');
     ^--------- index of array
```